# If we know the fundamental group of $X$, we know the fundamental group of $X/\sim$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to find the fundamental group of the cone, and this question appear on my mind:

Since we can defined the cone as $CX=X\times I/I\times \{1\}$, what we can say about $CX$? If we know the fundamental group of $X$, what we can say about the fundamental group of $CX$? We can generalize this to any relation $\sim$ ? I saw in a pdf the author says $\pi_1(cone)=1$ what he means with that? he doesn't specify which kind of cone is. I think maybe he says the cone in $\mathbb R^3$.

I need help.

Thanks

Comment: $CX$ deformation retracts to a point, and hence is contractible. Thus $\pi_1(CX) = 1$.

Comment: @RafaelChavez Here is an explicit deformation retract: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189989/38268

Comment: @BenjaLim thank you, it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in comments:

> CX deformation retracts to a point, and hence is contractible. Thus $\pi_1(CX)=1$. –  froggie Nov 25 '12 at 23:06

and

> Here is an explicit deformation retract: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189989/38268 –  user38268 Nov 26 '12 at 0:20